# Recursively look up and expand variables in Pegjs

Tags: javascript, parsing, language-design, peg, pegjs

Looking for a solution using something like PegJS (open to other suggestions) to recursively look up and expand variables.

The program can set variables to other variables or a number

given a structure like this:
`{$a: '1', $b: '$a + 2', $c: '$b + 10'}`

```
$a 
// looks up $a, expands to 1
$b 
// looks up $b, finds $a + 2, looks up $a and expands to 1 + 2
$c 
// looks up $c, finds $b + 10, looks up $b and finds $a + 2, looks up $a and expands to 1 + 2
```

What is best way (tool, or otherwise) to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution that might get you started. Define `obj = {}` in an initializer because you will want to have the object available while you are parsing to cache the keys as you find them.

```
{
    var obj = {};
}

obj =
    "{" _* keyPair* "}"
    {
        return obj;
    }

keyPair =
    key:key ":" _* val:singleQuoted _*
    {
        obj[key] = val;
    }

key =
    $("$" word)

expression =
    key:key _* "+" _* num:num
    {
        return obj[key] + num;
    }

singleQuoted =
    "'" exp:(expression / num) "'" ","?
    {
        return exp;
    }

num =
    num:$([0-9]+)
    {
        return parseInt(num);
    }

word =
    $([A-Za-z]+)

_ =
    " "
```